# Pass python function data to another function

Tags: python

to explain the process step by step, I take tokens from the `def producttoken():` function and delete each line in the list.csv with the help of the api in the `def product_delete(product_id):` function with the for loop. But in case the token expired, I want to renew the token again, but if I run the token function again in the if loop, the global variable tokens is not updated. It receives the new token constantly, but I cannot pass the updated token information to the `def product_delete` function.

```
import requests
import json

def producttoken():
  url = "https://productapi.com/tokens"
  payload = json.dumps({
  "Username": "*",
  "AppKey": "USER",
  "Hash": "hzh8123sdgxzc123sdfdfhI1tOY="})
  headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
  strigns=response.text
  stoken=str(strigns)
  jtoken=json.loads(stoken)
  token=jtoken['token']
  print("token taken")
  return token

tokens=producttoken()
counter = 0

def product_delete(product_id):
    product_delete_url = "https://productapi.com/products/id/"+product_id;
    headers = {
    'authorization': "Token"+tokens,
    'cache-control': "no-cache",}
    response = requests.request("DELETE", product_delete_url, headers=headers)
    r=response.text
    if "expired_token" in r:
        print("token renewed")
        producttoken()
    print(response.text)    
        
for line in open('list.csv','r'):
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    product_id = line.split(';')[0]
    counter = counter + 1
    product = product_delete(product_id)
    print(counter)
```

Comment: Note the different between `producttoken()` and the original line `tokens=producttoken()`. There's a key step you're missing in the "expired" renewal part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `tokens` as second parameter in `product_delete` function then using recursion to get new token and calling the function again with same `product_id`.

```
tokens = producttoken()
counter = 0


def product_delete(product_id, tokens):
    product_delete_url = "https://productapi.com/products/id/" + product_id
    headers = {
        'authorization': "Token" + tokens,
        'cache-control': "no-cache", }
    response = requests.request("DELETE", product_delete_url, headers=headers)
    r = response.text
    if "expired_token" in r:
        print("token renewed")
        product_delete(product_id, producttoken())
    print(response.text)


for line in open('list.csv', 'r'):
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    product_id = line.split(';')[0]
    counter = counter + 1
    product = product_delete(product_id, tokens)
    print(counter)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to update `token`, such as using the `class` base of your functions and using setter and getter. However, sending `token` in argument to product_delete might be easier for you:

```
product = product_delete(product_id, token)
```

I hope it could help you ;)